# Debugging Apostrophe CMS with breakpoints using apostrophe-monitor

Tags: apostrophe-cms

As a fairly new Apostrophe developer and not so node expert, I am able to successfully debug Apostrophe with nodemon by launching it with `--inspect-brk` arguments. However, I have tried to debug by launching the [`apostrophe-monitor`](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-monitor) module to no avail.

**[edit 2019-01-18]** By not "being able to debug" I mean the debugger is not properly attach to the process and breakpoints don't work. **[/edit]**

Although I am able to run it and it and usually I can experience a much faster reloading time, there is very high number of times (30%?) where, after refreshing my browser, the following error appears and I need to relaunch apostrophe-monitor:

```
Waiting for changes...
MongoError: Topology was destroyed
    at nextFunction (C:\Repo\apostrophe\monitor-test\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:547:27)
    at Cursor.next [as _next] (C:\Repo\apostrophe\monitor-test\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:701:3)
    at nextObject (C:\Repo\apostrophe\monitor-test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:680:8)
    at Cursor.next (C:\Repo\apostrophe\monitor-test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:270:12)
    at findOne (C:\Repo\apostrophe\monitor-test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:1414:10)
    at Collection.findOne (C:\Repo\apostrophe\monitor-test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:1400:44)
    at Collection.tryCatcher (C:\Repo\apostrophe\monitor-test\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Collection.ret [as findOneAsync] (eval at makeNodePromisifiedEval (C:\Repo\apostrophe\monitor-test\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promisify.js:184:12), <anonymous>:14:23)
```

This is just an empty scaffolded project with the following configuration:

package.json:

```
...
  "main": "app.js,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "debug": "nodemon --inspect-brk app.js",
    "monitor": "monitor --inspect-brk"
  },
...
```

app.js:

```
module.exports = require('apostrophe')({
  root: module,
  shortName: 'monitor-test',
  modules : { 
   ...
  }

});
```

VS Code launch.json:

```
...
{
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Nodemon",
            "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/app.js",
            "restart": true,
            //"console": "integratedTerminal",
            "useWSL": true,
            "args": ["--inspect-brk"],
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
        },{
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to node",
            "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
            "restart": true,
            "protocol": "inspector"
        }
...
```

And I run it with `npm run monitor`
Any idea?

Comment: We have seen this issue too. Seems to be 100% of the time on Windows, but only some of the time on MacOS. If I can nail down reproducing it where I can easily debug it, I will definitely ship a new release. We might even be able to do it by reusing the database connection, which would be a nice little performance win, along with perhaps reusing the listening socket.

Comment: Is there any more information I can provide you with? I would gladly debug the npm module, although I'm still too noobish in the Apostrophe world to try to nail down the issue and solve it myself.

About the debugging, are you able to debug by running monitor in Mac?

Comment: MacOS is my usual platform. I didn't see this bug on Mac myself, but a coworker says they can reproduce it, so we'll see. Would love to push apostrophe-monitor more.

Comment: I'm sorry, now I see I didn't explain myself well, I'm not using the right verb. My real problem here is that, although I can run apostrophe-monitor, my breakpoints don't get hit even with the `--inspect-brk` option. I'm going to edit my question, my apologies.

Comment: Oh I see. It shouldn't be possible for apostrophe-monitor to impact that, even if it wanted to (: It's too low-level.